Synthesizing multivariate time-series data with generative models for multiple data
I am new to multivariate time-series data and am particularly interested in synthesizing such data using generative models like TimeGAN: TimeGAN. From reading the literature on this topic, I have noticed that most of these methods are predominantly tested on datasets from single patients, with ECG5000 being one of the most cited examples, or Appliances Energy Prediction data for a single household.
I like to train a model that can effectively manage data from multiple patients or various devices/sensors. Would it be possible to use models such as TimeGAN for this purpose? If so, what modifications would be needed to adapt these models to handle the complexities of data from multiple sources?
